# DOMXML, PHP4 => PHP5

Tags: php, dom

I have a script running on a server with PHP4 that uses DOMXML. Now I have to migrate the site (incl. the script) to a new server running PHP5 and it seems that DOMXML isn't working properly anymore. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP5 the DOMXML was replaced by DOM:

http://www.php.net/manual/ref.dom.php

For migration check this page:

http://alexandre.alapetite.net/doc-alex/domxml-php4-php5/index.en.html

Comment: This looks like the thing I'm looking for. Thanks!