# phpQuery not working

Tags: php, phpquery

Hi friends i have downloaded the phpQuery plugin from their site . But whenever i try to run the phpQuery demo.php file i get the following error :-

Error:-

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
    "Old PHP4 DOM XML extension   detected. phpQuery won't work until this extension is enabled."
in   C:\wamp\www\phpQuery\phpQuery\phpQuery.php:483
Stack trace:
    #0 C:\wamp\www\phpQuery\phpQuery\phpQuery.php(271): phpQuery::createDocumentWrapper('<div/>',  NULL)
    #1 C:\wamp\www\phpQuery\demo.php(11): phpQuery::newDocument('<div/>')
    #2 {main} thrown in C:\wamp\www\phpQuery\phpQuery\phpQuery.php on line 483
```

My php version is 5.2.9-1.
What extra extension i need ? Can anyone help me out with this error ??

Comment: @zneak whats the problem ??

Comment: **Old PHP4 DOM XML extension   detected. phpQuery won't work until this extension is enabled.** error seems clear to me

Comment: Yup even i got the point, but do i need to add new extension and if so how >>

Comment: @PavanK, the problem was the formatting of your error message. If you click the "edited" link above, you'll see exactly what I've changed. Basically, I took your single-line error message and split it in multiple lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message is misleading. If you [look up phpQuery's source](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/source/browse/branches/dev/phpQuery/phpQuery.php?r=382#481), you'll see that it should indeed say the opposite: "phpQuery won't work until this extension is *disabled*". (Or at least, that's what the source code would lead me to believe, since functions stop to exist when you *disable* extensions, not when you *enable* them.)

The reference for this extension on the PHP website is no longer available, but [archive.org still has a copy of it](http://web.archive.org/web/20111006043413/https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxml.installation.php). This page tells us that the PHP4 DOM extension's DLL name is `php_domxml.dll`, so this is what you need to remove.

In your php.ini file, you need to comment the line where it says `extension=php_domxml.dll`. You can make it a comment by prefixing the line with a semicolon.

This all assumes you're not mistaken about your PHP version. I suggest you check a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to verify that you run the PHP version you're expecting, if you haven't already done so. I find it surprising that a PHP5 install would still use a PHP4 extension.

Answer (score 2):

phpQuery is trying to detect whether you have the PHP 4 [the DOM XML extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/domxml) on your system, or the [PHP 5 DOM extension](http://www.php.net/dom) that [superceded it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610124/domxml-php4-php5).

Unfortunately, it's lying to you about the outcome. You can see [the relevant phpQuery code here](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/source/browse/branches/dev/phpQuery/phpQuery.php?r=382#482):

```
if (function_exists('domxml_open_mem'))
    throw new Exception("Old PHP4 DOM XML extension detected. phpQuery won't work until this extension is enabled.");
```

It meant "disabled", not "enabled". You have to disable the "DOM XML" extension in your configuration.

This problem is filed as [phpQuery issue #224](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/issues/detail?id=224).

Comment: +1 Awesome! I had this problem once. I just installed PHP5 just as you had told. It worked! It worked!

Comment: @MarkGarcia: I'm glad to hear it.

Comment: I have php 5 ...I have even mentioned my php version , its 5.2.9-1

Comment: @PavanK: Double-check this, as it seems unlikely. Then check for the "domxml" extension in your configuration, and remove it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit First you mentioned enabled....yup after disabling it ,its working fine...

Comment: @PavanK: Yes, my mistake... and phpQuery's! I filed a bug with phpQuery so that they fix the text in the future.

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest that you **read the error message**. You have an old version of DOM XML.

You can obtain all the info you need regarding the new version at [the official docs](http://www.php.net/dom) - but it is installed by default so I would suggest you update your WAMP to the latest version.